# From A Method With In The Class Return An Instance Of The Class As An Interface Type That The Class Implements

Tags: vb.net, generics, interface

what I'm trying to archive with the code below is to have the `GetInstance` generic function take in an interface type that `SystemVars` implements (say IAuthentication) then create an instance of `SystemVars` and return it as interface type T.

The problem I an having is that no matter what casting method I try I can't find a way to return the new instance of `SystemVars` as T. The line in the `GetInstance` method `Return <CastingFunction>(New SystemVars,T)` always fails to compile with the error message saying *Value of type SystemVars cannot be converted to 'T'.*

How do I return the instance of the class as the interface type that was passed into T?

```
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class SystemVars
    Implements IAuthentication,
               IAuthorization,
               IApplicationStarting

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub


    Public Shared Function GetInstance(Of T)() As T
        Return DirectCast(New SystemVars, T)
    End Function


    Public ReadOnly Property Username As String _
        Implements IAuthentication.Username,
                   IAuthorization.Username
        Get
            Return _userName
        End Get
    End Property


    Public ReadOnly Property Rolls As List(Of String) _
        Implements IAuthorization.Rolls
        Get
            Return _rolls
        End Get
    End Property


    Public ReadOnly Property InstallationId As Guid _
        Implements IAuthentication.InstallationId,
                   IApplicationStarting.InstallationId
        Get
            Return _installationId
        End Get
    End Property


    Public ReadOnly Property MainWindowStartUpPlacement As Rectangle _
        Implements IApplicationStarting.MainWindowStartUpPlacement
        Get
            Return _mainWindowStartUpPlacement
        End Get
    End Property

    '........

    Private Shared _userName As String
    Private Shared _rolls As List(Of String)
    Private Shared _installationId As Guid
    Private Shared _mainWindowStartUpPlacement As Rectangle
End Class
```

Comment: Why would you need to use a generic method that returns an interface type that you need to specify when you could use a non-generic method that returns a class reference that you then cast as that same interface type?

Comment: Why should that work? `T` can be absolutely anything in that code. It doesn't even have to be an interface, never mind one that `SystemWars` implements? What if someone called `SystemWars.GetInstance(Of String)()`?

Comment: @user18387401 Thanks for looking at my question and commenting. The reason for not returning an instance of the class and then casting it is that I was trying to stop my code from having access to all the system variables, if I return an instance as a interface then only a concise subset of the system variables that the use case uses will be available to it. Regarding your point of passing in a string, I had hoped it would just throw an invalid cast exception so if I do something like that my unit tests should pick up my mistake.

Comment: *"a concise subset of the system variables"*. I have no idea what that means. If you're suggesting that the calling code should know the interface types but not the class type then that doesn't work because you're calling the method on the class in the first place. I don't know what system variables you're referring to or what concise set you may be referring to either.

Comment: @user18387401 Sorry for not being clear.  The above class holds all the state for my application (and is much bigger and implements more interfaces than the fragment I posted). What I was trying to achieve was a way for a use case to get access to _only_ the state that it uses, which is why I wanted to return the `SystemVars` instance as an Interface type thereby restricting access to only the properties defined on the interface that was passed in. A way to say 'Hay I'm the Authentication Use case, just give me back the state that applies to me'.  I hope that's clearer.

Comment: But the calling code has to specify the interface via which it wants to access the object either way, sop what's the difference? Your method would let you do `Dim obj = SystemWars.GetInstance(Of ISomeInterface)()`, so the calling code gets to choose any interface it wants anyway. What does that achieve over using `Dim obj = DirectCast(SystemWars.GetInstance(), ISomeInterface)`? I guess it means that you cannot access members that aren't from an interface but, if there aren't any of them, you aren't achieving anything with that generic method.

Comment: Even using your generic method, the caller could still cast the interface reference to type `SystemWars` and access the rest of the members anyway.

Comment: @user18387401 The difference, in my mind, between `DirectCast(SytemVars.GetInstance(),ISomeInterface)` and `GetInstance(of SomeInterface)` is the principle of 'Tell Don't Ask'.  `DirectCast(SytemVars.GetInstance(),ISomeInterface)`  'asks' `GetInstance` to return an object containing all state values and leaves it up to the caller as to what it's going to do with it. `GetInstance(of SomeInterface)` 'tells' `GetInstance` what state values it must return. As far as stopping access to `SystemVars` by deliberate casting I agree with you, it doesn't.

Comment: Note that the general kind of thing you're doing is often implemented using DI containers, where SystemVars would be registered as the underlying type for the interfaces, and a client would ask the container for the interface.  This is a kind of a service location pattern, and you may find some commentators who view that pattern negatively in general, though I think something like this usage isn't necessarily a negative (you seem to be asking the right kinds of questions about it).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure of the distinction between `SystemVars.GetInstance(Of IAuthentication)` and something like `TryCast(SystemVars.GetInstance, IAuthentication)`.  The DI approach would end up being something like `Container.GetInstance(Of IAuthentication)` (and the calling code wouldn't even necessarily know about `SystemVars`).

Comment: @Craig The distinction  for me between the 2 casting methods was where the casting is done   and what is returned from `GetInstance()`. In my eyes `Trycast(SystemVars.GetInstance,IAuthentication) `  means  `GetInstance` returns a `SystemVars` object and 'hopes' it's used appropriately by the caller. `SystemVars.GetInstance(of IAuthentication)` does the casting inside of `GetInstance` and returns the `SystemVars` instance as an Interface type, but after reading @user18387401 comments a number of times I think I've got a bit obsessive over this point.

Comment: I read and lesson to a lot of Uncle Bob's  stuff and he teaches that your objects should 'Tell' other objects what to do, not 'ask' them for there state. Also he teaches that you shouldn't allow objects to depend on 'things' they don't need. That's what was motivating my thinking when I started down this path. 'Tell' `SystemVars` what system variables I need and get access to just the system variables I need (through the interface)  so I don't have access to stuff I don't need (being the whole of the `SystemVars` object). But my interpretation of this teaching might be well of the mark here.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from.  I think, ideally, you end up with one fairly high-level point where `SystemVars` is associated with one or more interfaces.  There are a few different ways to do that association, and I'm not sure that any one is necessarily better than another.  At this level, I'm not sure "tell" and "ask" are particularly relevant; after this point, you'll be telling clients "This is the implementation if IWhatever that you need".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an otherwise illegal cast work by passing through `Object`.

```vb
Public Shared Function GetInstance(Of T)() As T
    Return DirectCast(CObj(New SystemVars), T)
End Function
```

You will get a runtime error if the cast isn't possible; as noted in the comments, this strategy is chucking type safety out the window and basically telling the compiler, "Don't bother me, I know what I'm doing."  The runtime will throw an `InvalidCastException` on failure if you don't test and throw yourself.  You can test using `Type.IsAssignableFrom` if you want to create a more developer-friendly error message; there isn't much context available in the debugger at the point of failure, though it may be pretty obvious if you look up the call stack.

For just three interfaces, it might be better to do three separate specific functions rather than a generic version, especially considering that the functions are necessarily `Shared` (and thus can't themselves be part of an interface).

You might also consider a design that includes a Dependency Injection container.  In this kind of design, there would be a configuration step that would associate the interfaces with `SystemVars` as the implementation, then the client would ask the container for an instance of the interface and receive a `SystemVars` object.

The rough way that the three options (the third being to cast the `SystemVars` object to the requested interface) would look in code is:

```vb
'Casting a received object to a requested interface
Dim asInterface = DirectCast(SystemVars.GetInstance(), IAuthorization)

'Using a custom casting function on SystemVars
Dim asInterface = SystemVars.GetInstance(Of IAuthorization)

'Using a DI container
'Behavior if the interface isn't supported depends on the container
Dim asInterface = container.GetInstance(Of IAuthorization)
```

Note that `TryCast` could be used instead of `DirectCast`, in which case the result would be `Nothing` if the interface isn't supported.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question and for the extra information and guidance you provided, it was very useful and is a great answer.

Comment: @CodeAdze After some more thought, I expanded it a bit.  Hope you find the additional material helpful.

Comment: The extra material and explanation is VERY helpful, thank you so much for taking the time to add it. I haven't used a DI container before but sounds like it might be just the ticket. I will look into this approach. I guess that will mean I will need a DI framework?? of some type. Can you recommend one that your like? Thanks again.

Comment: @CodeAdze I'm afraid I don't have much experience with selection of DI frameworks.  The software that I work on for my employer uses the Microsoft Prism design, so I have some experience with Microsoft's Unity container.  I don't have any experience with other alternatives.